# How data will load in to memory in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner in sql server.I have read about buffer cache in sql server.I think it is the location in system RAM where the data will be stored once the query is executed.If that is correct,i have a few questions about query execution.

1)If my RAM size is 2GB, and i have data in my sql server of 10GB size and if i execute the sqlstatment for retreiving all the data(10 GB) from database,what will happen(Work/Not work)?

2)In the same case, if multiple user execute queries for retrieving 5 GB each(total 10 GB),what will happen?

Comment: It's *questions* not *doubts*...

Comment: @Yuck http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question

Comment: @Curt It was brought up on meta as well. The trouble with this literal translation is that it *typically* has very negative connotations for native English speakers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you issue a `SELECT * FROM [MyTable]` and your table has 10Gb on a system that has only 2Gb of RAM a database does not have to read the entire 10 Gb *at once* in memory. The select will start a [scan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181129.aspx) of the data, starting with the first [data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969.aspx) page. For this it only needs that page (which is 8Kb) in memory, so it reads the page and consumes 8Kb of RAM. As it scans this page, it produces output that you see as the result set. As soon as is done with this page, it needs the next page so it read is in memory. It scans the records in it and produces output for your result. Then next page, then next page. The key point is that once is done with a page, its no longer needed. As it keeps adding these 8kb pages into RAM, they will eventually add up and consume all free RAM. In that moment SQL will *free* the old, unused, pages in RAM and thus make room for new ones. It will keep doing so until the entire 10Gb of your table are read.

If there are two users reading a table of 5GB each, things work exactly the same. Each user's query is scanning only one page at a time, and as they make progress and keep reading pages, they will fill up the RAM. When all the available RAM is used, SQL will start discarding old pages from RAM to make room for new ones.

In the real world things are fancier because of considerations like [read-ahead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475.aspx).

And as a side note, you should never scan 10Gb of data. Your application should always request only the data it needs, and the data should be retrievable fast by using an index, exactly to avoid such large scan that needs to examine the entire table.

Comment: "The key point is that once is done with a page, its no longer needed." - what about for tables that are frequently-accessed?  It's important for SQL Server to store that stuff in memory as it's way more efficient than going to/from disk.

Answer (score 2):

Thankfully you don't have to worry about this. Sure, it is important to tune your queries, minimize resultsets for network transfer, etc. etc. but SQL Server has been around a long time and it's very good at its own memory management. Unless you encounter a specific query that misbehaves, I'd say don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, data retrieved goes into the buffer cache. Some of that is real memory, some is spooled off to disk.

You can observe whether or not you're reusing memory by watching the Page Life Expectancy performance counter (there other indicators too, but this one is a quick shorthand). If you run a query that returns huge amounts of data and pushes other data out of the cache, you can watch the page life expectancy drop. As you run lots & lots of small queries, you can see the page life expectancy grow, sometimes to a lenght of days & days.

It's not a great measure for memory pressure on the system, but it can give you an indication of how well you're seeing the data in cache get reused.

Answer (score 1):

the full resultset of a query is not stored on the RAM by sql server for reusing. What can be stored is the execution plan used on a query.

SQL Server stores data to manipulate it, like on an update statement, it reads the data from the DB, stores on the RAM, edit it and then another process writes it back to the DB. BUt as @n8wrl said, you dont need to worry about it.

Comment: Actually, the biggest part of memory inside SQL Server is the buffer cache and that is literally the data read from disk, stored in memory, so that, hopefully, it can be reused with multiple queries. In short, the result set of a query is stored in RAM, if there's enough RAM. If not, it cycles through what it can. You can watch this occur by observing pagelifeexpectancy.

Comment: true, but this is a very complex scenario withe several possibilities. Imagine your select returns 2 rows and they are cached as you said. If one of them is changed on the DB the cache becomes obsolete. If the same select is ran again, will SQL Server read data from the cache, the DB or one line from each? To complicate even more, you can add concurrency, diferent transaction isolation levels, etc..  :) 
Anyway, It will produce the right result, of course as @n8wrl said, but how it does we would need someone with a lot of knowledge on the internal behavior of SQL Server to tell us

Comment: If the data changes, it gets marked as dirty within the cache. As a matter of fact, the changes to the data are done in cache first, then transferred to the disk. You can read up about it in Chapter 1 of Kalen Delaney's excellent book, SQL Server 2008 Internals, pages 30,31.